# How to use sub in R with numeric operations on the matches?

Tags: r, regex, pattern-matching

Let's say I want to change the string `X0_Y1_Z2` into `X0_Y1_Z1`, i.e. to decrease the last number by one. I tried it by the following statement in R, which doesn't work:

```
sub("(\\S+_\\S+_)\\S(\\d)", paste0("\\1", as.numeric("\\2")-1), "X0_Y1_Z2", perl=T)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Can it be `"X0_Y1_Z222"`? Do you also need to validate the string (your pattern seem to require a specific pattern)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always have the string in this same format, and you only have 1 last digit to decrement, use a simple `substring`:

```
> paste0(substring(s, 1, nchar(s)-1), as.numeric(substring(s, nchar(s))) - 1)
> [1] "X0_Y1_Z1"
```

In order to match the last digit chunk in a string, use `[0-9]+$` regex. To increase the value, use `gsubfn` package. See an example code:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> s <- "X0_Y1_Z2"
> gsubfn('[0-9]+$', ~ as.numeric(x)-1, s)
[1] "X0_Y1_Z1"
```

If you need to validate the string the way you did, use more groups and the anchors `^` and `$` will require the whole string to match the pattern (a "full string match"):

```
> p <- "^(\\S+_\\S+_\\S)(\\d+)$"
> gsubfn(p, function(x1,x2) paste0(x1, as.numeric(x2)-1), s)
[1] "X0_Y1_Z1"
```

Comment: Thanks! The gsubfn package seems to do the trick. I will use it.